# Rails app connected to empty db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

n00b question.

It appears as if my rails app isn't connecting to a database, based on my seeing the pages loaded in the browser having no items.

OR at least, it appears it's connected to an empty database:

From the rails console:

```
irb(main):004:0> Item.count
(0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "items"
=> 0
```

Which is strange because I definitely have data in there according to my view in pgAdmin.

Here's my database.yml file:

```
common: &common
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV['DB_POOL'] %>

development:
  <<: *common
  database: <%= ENV['DB_DEV_DATABASE'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DB_DEV_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_DEV_PASSWORD'] %>
  host:     <%= ENV['DB_DEV_HOST'] %>
  port:     <%= ENV['DB_DEV_PORT'] %>

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *common
  database: <%= ENV['DB_TEST_DATABASE'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DB_TEST_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_TEST_PASSWORD'] %>
  host:     <%= ENV['DB_TEST_HOST'] %>
  port:     <%= ENV['DB_TEST_PORT'] %>

staging:
  <<: *common
  database: <%= ENV['DB_STAGING_DATABASE'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DB_STAGING_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_STAGING_PASSWORD'] %>
  host:     <%= ENV['DB_STAGING_HOST'] %>
  port:     <%= ENV['DB_STAGING_PORT'] %>

production:
  <<: *common
  database: <%= ENV['DB_DATABASE'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DB_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>
  host:     <%= ENV['DB_HOST'] %>
  port:     <%= ENV['DB_PORT'] %>
```

Comment: Can you run the following within Rails console `Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]` and report on the output? This will at least confirm the database you're connected to.

Comment: => {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>nil, "database"=>nil, "username"=>nil, "password"=>nil, "host"=>nil, "port"=>nil}

Comment: So it looks like your environment variables (`ENV['DB_DEV_DATABASE']` etc.) are not properly set or the application is having trouble reading them. Are you certain those environment variables are set.?

Comment: I believe they are not set.  I ran command 'env' from the terminal and I don't see any of them listed.  Is there a file within the app that they should be set in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling your environment variables (`ENV['DB_DEV_DATABASE']`) are not properly set. You can either set them as per your shell environment (bash, zsh, etc.). For example, if you're working within a bash environment, you would need to add the following into your `~/.bashrc` file.

```
export DB_DEV_DATABASE="yourapp_development"
# etc.
```

Or you can forego the environment variables and set the values directly within your `database.yml`

```
common: &common
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode

development:
  <<: *common
  database: yourapp_development
  username: username
  password: password
  host:     localhost
```